# add 3rd box outside of the 2nd

Tags: html, css

I wrote a simple code to have two boxes center aligned with different dimensions
and now I would like to add a third one based on the dimensions of the second one (grey) and to start outside of the second one.
The second one (grey) is the core and the third one that I want to be the coil around the core but with it's own dimensions.
That's why I want to be based on the dimensions of second.
Please could you help me to make it?
Thank you very much in advance!

Kind Regards,
George

Here is the code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #container {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .box1 {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                margin: 50px;
                background: black;
                height: 50px;
                width: 200px;
                border-radius:20px
            }

            .box2 {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                margin: -1000px;
                background: grey;
                height: 10px;
                width: 100px;
                border-radius:5px
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <div id="container">

        <div class="box1">
            <div class="box2">
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div><!-- end #container -->
</html>
```

Comment: can you share a screenshot of what you want

Answer (score 1):

So considering the grey as the core and the red border around it as the coil. Is this how you wanted it to be done?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 50px;
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 20px
}

.box2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: -1000px;
  background: grey;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.box2:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="box2">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end #container -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response. Looks fine but it's not exactly that I want. I want the coil to start of the outside of the core like yours but when I change the dimensions to start to cover the black base. To see how much coil fits around core (grey) and base (black). Is this something possible?

Thank you again! George